# Can I halve a macaron recipe and expect the same cooking temperature and time?

Tags: baking, cooking-time, macarons

I'm about to try a macaron recipe at home; I'd like to start with a half volume in case they turn out particularly badly. Given the macarons will be on a single tray in the oven I can't think of a reason why cooking temperature or time would be different to the full recipe – is there anything I haven't thought of that I should be aware of? Of course I will try to check that they're ready from appearance/texture etc. anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might see a tiny reduction in cooking time due to the smaller thermal load, but this is more a theoretical than a practical point. The difference will be smaller than normal variation between ovens. Check for doneness as you would usually, and you will be fine.